# Retrieve most retweeted tweets for a given hashtag

Tags: twitter

I'd like to retrieve the tweets for given a hashtag and sort them from the most retweeted to the less retweeted.

The closest thing I've found is using the search call and use the type tag:
E.g.: http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=TheHashTagHere&result_type=popular

However, I'm not sure on how "popular" option works.

For instance, if it finds 100 tweets with that hashtag I believe it should show the X most retweeted tweets, and if none of those tweets have been retweeted then it should show X of them randomly (or sorted in some other way like the most recent).

Unfortunately, if follows some kind of unknown rule to identify what's popular and what not and even hashtags with thousands of tweets might return only one or two results.

I hope I made myself clear. Thanks in advance :)

PS: I'll use PHP but I think that shouldn't affect the question?

Comment: Do you think you could show me all of the code for using this particular API. I'm trying to do something very similar and don't exactly know how to approach this. Thanks

Comment: Well, GmonC's answer and mine contain pretty much everything you need. Sorry I don't have my code with me right now but checking  http://dev.twitter.com/ should help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Results will sometimes contain a
> result_type field into the metadata
> with a value of either "recent" or
> "popular". Popular results are derived
> **by an algorithm that Twitter computes**,
> and up to 3 will appear in the default
> mixed mode that the Search API
> operates under. Popular results
> include another node in the metadata
> called **recent_retweets**. This field
> indicates **how many retweets** the Tweet
> has had.

[Source](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/using_search) (Emphasis are mine)

Just call with [`result_type=popular`](http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=python&result_type=popular) and check the `recent_retweets` node to see how popular it is. `result_type=popular` [will become the default](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search) in an upcome release so beware if you omit this parameter.

Results with popular tweets aren't ordered chronologically. *

If you would like to always have results to show, use [`result_type=mixed`](http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=python&result_type=mixed): they will have the `result_type` in the "metadata" section with a value of "recent", and popular results will have "popular". A small reference about result_types:

> **mixed**: Include both popular and real time results in the response.
>
> **recent**: return only the most recent results in the response
>
> **popular**: return only the most popular results in the response.

If a search query has any popular results, those will be returned at the top, even if they are older than the other results. *

*[[Twitter API Announcements](http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-api-announce/msg/0fea51615c0d207e)]

Comment: SO there is no way of sorting the results by how many times they've been retweeted then, right? Popular tweets aside...

Comment: @ozke: Receiving the data as json, you can convert them using json_decode http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php and sort yourself the way you want.

Comment: But the number of retweets variable only appears on those marked by tweeter as popular, isn't it? If a tweet has 2 or 3 retweets u won't know. Am I right?

Comment: @ozke: Yes, the retweets variable appears only on 'popular' unfortunately (although I can't answer about the 2 or 3 RT, since this is an internal Twitter algorithm). As you can see on the two examples I posted (using mixed and popular requests), you can only see the retweets information by those 'popular' nodes.

Comment: I guess what I am asking for is impossible then (at least with the current API). Thanks for your great help though. The bounty is for you :)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a programmatic method but rather works in the browser with a chrome extension ([HackyBird](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hackybird/ddlhmpomfloaidpdleeoegmpikjdchjf)) :

- Install the [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hackybird/ddlhmpomfloaidpdleeoegmpikjdchjf)
- Search for a phrase e.g. #Social (twitter.com/search?q=%23Social)
- Click the extension to sort it (you can adjust the ratio of retweets/likes used for sorting in extension options).

P.S. It'll also sort your or any other user's timeline.