# Retrieve most retweeted tweets for a given keyword

Tags: php, json, api, search, twitter

There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046725/retrieve-most-retweeted-tweets-for-a-given-hashtag) on SO but its months old and it also went unanswered, plus it was for Hashtag. So I thought I'd ask again:

I'd like to retrieve the tweets for given a **keyword** between a **given time** and sort them from the **most retweeted** to the less retweeted.

I checked the Twitter API doc but couldn't figure how it can be done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `since` and `until` operators to sort the tweets between two dates. In addition you can use the `result_type=popular`.

the combined call would be something like this

> http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23superbowl&result_type=popular+since%3A2012-01-22+until%3A2012-01-29

The search API only saves results for a short time window. Up to 10-14 days or so.

You might want to look into an API like Snapbird to circumvent this limit

https://github.com/remy/snapbird

-- update

to get retweets, you'll need to feed in each ID and then look into the retweet count field.

Look into the API console for the retweet call to test against, https://dev.twitter.com/console

There is no way currently, for the search API to give you this information with one call. You will need to run the search to get I.D's and then run the second step of the process.

Another option is to use the Streaming API, but it will not work with historical data, so this seems to be outside of your use case.

Comment: You probably missed the question, I need to find the *most retweeted* to less retweeted. popular is just twitter internal measurement of "popular"

Comment: More than one call is fine, can you please show an example with say "jailbreak" as the keyword during a period of "last month (30 days)"? Thanks!

Comment: in PHP?I 'm going to have to help more tomorrow as its 130am here. You would need to use snapbird and feed ids to retweet call.

Comment: Not necessarily PHP, your preferred lang would be fine. Sure, thanks

Comment: You were going to provide an example? :)

Comment: Yeah, it would be a bit too involved to get into. it's like writing a miniature app because you have to search to get ID's of popular tweets, then scrape the i.d's from Snapbird, then feed the i.d's to `tweet_status` one by one, then get the retweet count of said id, then sort associated i.d's by retweet count number. I'm in the middle of developing a chrome extension right now. This info should help you a lot. Go to the console I mentioned. The `http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show/{id}.json` call refers to retweet count per tweet.

Comment: {"errors": [{"message": "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.", "code": 68}]}